# Calculating the percentage of half

Tags: ios, swift, animation, math

My maths sucks so I need some help on this one as it's taken me 2 hours so far and i've got no where.

I have a touch enabled sliding panel (much like the "swipe to reveal" function you get on table cells). Here's an ugly ascii diagram

```
-----------------------------
|   Slide          | Reveal |
-----------------------------
```

You slide the "slide" bit left, to show the reveal bit. What I now want to do is work out, how much of the reveal is being shown when the touch ends, and either snap to open or closed.

I know that the reveal box width is 110, I can also work out that if the slide has moved left by -75, then the "open percentage" is 75%

```
Open Percentage = left / width
```

I want the animation time to be 0.5 seconds from the centre. So if you are at 50% it takes 0.5 seconds to snap open, and 49% takes 0.5 seconds to snap close (or thereabouts, I know 49% would be a touch under 0.5 secs)

Likewise, if the slider is only 20% open it should take 0.1 seconds to snap close, and 80% open is 0.1 seconds to snap open.

I believe I need to work out the left offset, relative to half width, calculate the percentage and then apply that percentage to the 0.5 max animation time... But that's where I get stuck.

Update: This is what I managed to get working after some trail and error, but it feels verbose and messy. Definately an easier way!

```
            // Config
            let maxAnimationTime = 0.5

            // Get left offset
            let absLeftOffset = abs(cell.leftContstraint.layoutConstraints[0].constant)

            // Get width of action box
            let actionBoxWidth = cell.revealView.frame.width
            let halfActionBoxWidth = actionBoxWidth / 2

            // Are we opening or closing?
            let snapOpen = absLeftOffset > halfActionBoxWidth

            // Calculate the left position relative the half width
            let xPos = snapOpen ? absLeftOffset - halfActionBoxWidth : absLeftOffset

            // Calculate the percentage of the left percentage relative to the half width
            let perc = snapOpen ? abs(xPos - halfActionBoxWidth) / halfActionBoxWidth : xPos / halfActionBoxWidth

            // Use the percentage to calculate the animation time to apply
            let animationTime = (Double(perc) * maxAnimationTime).round(to: 2)
```

Comment: If you know the percentage can you not just use that value for the animation time? If its less than or equal to 50 percent, just use the percentage value for the animation time and if its greater than 50 then use `100 - percentageValue` as the animation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it takes 0.5 seconds to snap from half way across, to snap the whole way it would take 1 second. Your snap time is merely the percentage of the whole width it has to snap multiplied by the time taken to travel across the whole wifth.

So if the slider is snapping open, it should take `1.0 x %from_left` and if it is snapping closed, it should take `1.0 x %from_right`

Note, in the below, although I talk about percent, I mean a fraction between 0 and 1.

First calculate % from right:

```
let rightPercent = Double(displacementFromRight) / Double(width)
```

if it is greater than or equal to 0.5, you need to calculate the leftPercent. The leftPercent is 1 - rightPercent.

If rightPercent is less than 0.5 you already have the right percentage, so putting it all together:

```
let maxDuration: Double = 1 // Maximum snap time in seconds
let duration: Double
if rightPercent >= 0.5
{
    // we will snap open
    duration = (1 - rightPercent) * maxDuration
}
else
{ 
    // we will snap closed
    duration = rightPercent * maxDuration
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I just posted an update my question to show what I managed to achieve. Your solution is so much more condensed, not sure why I didn't think of it, seems so simple now it's been explained! Thanks for your help, i'll go delete the ugly code I did and use yours :D